# Sending large array from Arduino to PC

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm tring to send a byte array from arduino due to a C# windows form app. The problem is that not the full array is arriving. The first 100-200 bytes are correct, but the others are all zero. It's fully random how much are correct. Here is my arduino abd C# code.

```
if (commandString.equals("IMPOR")) {
  digitalWrite(led2Pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led3Pin, LOW);
  byte buf[2048];
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    if (Serial.availableForWrite() > 2) {
      byte lb = SRAM.readByte(2 * i);
      byte hb = SRAM.readByte(2 * i + 1);
      int16_t raw2 = word(hb, lb);
      buf[2 * i] = raw2 & 255;
      buf[2 * i + 1] = (raw2 >> 8)  & 255;
    }
  }
  Serial.write(buf,sizeof(buf));
  digitalWrite(led2Pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3Pin, HIGH);
}
```

And c#:

```
int[] bdata = new int[1024];
private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytes = 2048; // ComPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes]; //Párosak a low bytok. Páratlanok a hugh byteok
        ComPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        int[] intbuffer = Array.ConvertAll(buffer, x => (int)x);
        //int[] bdata = new int[bytes / 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            bdata[i] = intbuffer[2 * i + 1] * 256 + intbuffer[2 * i];
        }
    }
```

DatarecievedTreshlod is set to 2048.
Here is a picture from the debug:
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1hQK.png)

Is there anyone who has idea what could be the problem? The SRAM is 23LCV512.

Comment: I'mm not very knowledgeable on C#, but `int[] intbuffer = Array.ConvertAll(buffer, x => (int)x);` looks very suspicious. To my eye it looks like you're converting all 2048 bytes into 2048 `int` values, not 1024 `int` values in the specified byte order.

Comment: The `Read` method usually returns the number of bytes actually read - this may be less than the requested amount, due to the OS using a smaller buffer than your byte array for example. You can't assume that all the data will be returned in one `Read` call, you either have to use a loop or wrap the serial port in a buffered stream

Comment: Sending raw data over a communications link is not sensible.  First you need human intervention to start and synchronize the programs on each end.  Then you assume that the link is perfect and free from noise/interference.  When the transfer ends there is no confirmation that all the data was received intact and correctly.

Comment: Your Arduino code to fill `buf[]` makes no sense to me.  First why is copying each word conditional on `Serial.availableForWrite() > 2`?  Secondly the low byte & high byte conversion to half-word operations all seems to be superfluous.  You're fetching in little-endian order, and then storing in little-endian order.  There's no change in byte order!

Comment: @sawdust Serial.vailableForWrite has been used in a previous version. It’s a mistake that stayed in the code. In the previous program I tried to send ten datas in a 2 bytes package. Because it doesn’t work i tried to send in one package. It has a lot of noise and false data. I send from the Arduino 2048 bytes and more than 2200 arrived.